# How to express && and || with just using -> and neg

Tags: boolean, computer-science

How to express "AND" and "OR" by just using "Implies" and "Negation"?

I tried 10+ combination for AND but non of them worked out:

I tried:   (X -> Y) -> ( X -> Y) , !(X -> Y) -> (X -> Y) , !(X -> Y) -> !(X -> Y)
(X -> Y) -> !(X -> Y) etc.

Comment: It might be easier to express `->` in terms of AND and OR, see what that gives you, and work backwards.

Comment: But my task is to show that implication and negation are universal, so I have to show that I can use then instead of AND and OR !

Comment: BTW, you do not need negation to express disjunction. A∨B is equal to (A⊃B)⊃B.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because such questions are best asked at https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and are off topic here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254764/162698

Comment: @StanislavKralin is negation by itself universal e.g can we use just Negation to express all possible Boolean functions?

Comment: @Dan Since negation only takes one value, not two, it would be impossible to implement any binary operations like AND using just negation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can cheat and use truth tables to figure it out. Truth tables for `->`, `!`, `&&` and `||` look like:

```
X    Y    X->Y    ~X    ~Y    X && Y    X || Y
T    T    T       F     F     T         T
T    F    F       F     T     F         T
F    T    T       T     F     F         T
F    F    T       T     T     F         F
```

We see that `&&` has one `T` and `||` has one `F`. `||` is actually pretty close to `->`; it just has the `F` shifted from where `X` is `F` to where `X` is `T`. When you see something like that your first thought should be to negate variables to exchange the corresponding sections of the truth table; by negating `X` in `X -> Y`, we should exchange sections of the truth table and get the values coming out the same as `X && Y`. Indeed,

```
X    Y    ~X    ~X -> Y    X || Y
T    T    F     T          T
T    F    F     T          T
F    T    T     T          T
F    F    F     F          F
```

That's one down. For `&&`, we see it's similar, except that we have one `T` instead of one `F` as `->`. When you see this, thing negating the whole thing:

```
X    Y    X && Y    !(X && Y)
T    T    T         F
T    F    F         T
F    T    F         T
F    F    F         T
```

Now we see we need to negate `Y` to swap the first and second rows of the truth table for `->`:

```
X    Y    !Y    X -> !Y    !(X -> !Y)
T    T    F     F          T
T    F    T     T          F
F    T    F     T          F
F    F    T     T          F
```

This comes out as required. It's all a matter of seeing what you have to work with - where you're starting - and understanding where you need to get to, and then working from either or both ends to figure out the linkage. In these cases, it was convenient to think in terms of "number of `T`s", but you might find something more useful depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

(a -> b) is the same as ((! a) || b)

from that it follows that ((! a) -> b) is the same as ((! (! a)) || b)

so ((! a) -> b) gives you (a || b)

For && I suggest you look up something called the De Morgan laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Thank you very much, but I had to give the best answer to the other one since it was an answer for both of them, thank you very much again :)

Comment: :)))) The answer above is also written more beautifully.